# Go: Property exists but Go compiler says it doesn't?

Tags: go, tdd

filelogger.go

```
package logger

import (
    "io"
)

type FileLogger struct{
    File io.Writer
}

func NewFileLogger(file io.Writer) *FileLogger{
    return &FileLogger{file}
}

func (this *FileLogger) Log(message string) error {
    _, err := this.File.Write([]byte(appendNewLine(message)))

    return err
}
```

filelogger_test.go:

```
package logger

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

type WriterMock struct{
    data []byte
}

func (this WriterMock) Write(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    this.data = append(this.data, b ...)

    return len(this.data), nil
}

func NewMockedFileLogger() *FileLogger{
    writer := WriterMock{}

    fileLogger := FileLogger{writer}

    return &fileLogger
}

func TestLog(t *testing.T) {
    fileLogger := NewMockedFileLogger()

    fileLogger.Log("Hello World!")

    assert.Equal(t, "Hello World!", string(fileLogger.File.data))
}
```

My problem:

I'm getting this error message when running go test:

```
fileLogger.File.data undefined (type io.Writer has no field or method data)
```

`file.Logger.File` is indeed of `type io.Writer`, but this field `data` exists, I know Go is a strongly typed language, that's why it's not accepting this.

How can solve this?

Comment: Please don't use [`this` as a receiver name](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#receiver-names). It was a poor idea that some languages force you to use magic special names and it's a bad idea idea to continue that with languages that don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The writer `File` in a `FileLogger` is an [interface](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) ([`io.Writer`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer)), not a `struct`.

You would need a **[type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)** in order to access `data` of `WriterMock`:

```
fileLooger.File.(*WriterMock).data
```

(Note: that would fail if File was not a `*WriterMock`: more on that below)

---

See [this simplified example](https://play.golang.org/p/FN4N1o_dlD):

package main

```
import "fmt"
import "io"

type WriterMock struct {
    data []byte
}

func (this WriterMock) Write(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    this.data = append(this.data, b...)

    return len(this.data), nil
}

func main() {
    var w io.Writer = &WriterMock{}
    fmt.Printf("Hello, playground '%+v'", w.(*WriterMock).data)
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, playground '[]'
```

### ----

Since a type asertion car error, and you should always check the error, consider the section "[Interface conversions and type assertions](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions)":

> But if it turns out that the value does not contain a string, the program will crash with a run-time error.
>   To guard against that, use the "comma, ok" idiom to test, safely, whether the value is a string:

```
str, ok := value.(string)
if ok {
    fmt.Printf("string value is: %q\n", str)
} else {
    fmt.Printf("value is not a string\n")
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time making this test pass, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28928870/go-test-cannot-pass