# Go: Test cannot pass?

Tags: go, tdd

I'm having a problem making this test pass. The problem is, the `Write()` method in my struct needs to write to a property, but `io.Writer` interface does not accept pointer as its receiver.

```
filelogger.go:

package logger

import (
    "io"
)

type FileLogger struct{
    File io.Writer
}

func NewFileLogger(file io.Writer) *FileLogger{
    return &FileLogger{file}
}

func (this *FileLogger) Log(message string) error {
    _, err := this.File.Write([]byte(appendNewLine(message)))

    return err
}

filelogger_test.go:

package logger

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

type WriterMock struct{
    data []byte
}

func (this WriterMock) Write(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    this.data = append(this.data, b ...)

    return len(this.data), nil
}

func NewMockedFileLogger() *FileLogger{
    writer := WriterMock{}

    fileLogger := FileLogger{writer}

    return &fileLogger
}

func TestLog(t *testing.T) {
    fileLogger := NewMockedFileLogger()

    fileLogger.Log("Hello World!")

    assert.Equal(t, "Hello World!", string(fileLogger.File.(WriterMock).data))
}
```

Test Output:

```
--- FAIL: TestLog (0.00 seconds)
        Location:       filelogger_test.go:32
    Error:      Not equal: "Hello World!" (expected)
                    != "" (actual)

FAIL
```

As I mentioned, the `data []byte` is not being written to, because I cannot set the function receiver as a pointer, as it won't satisfty the `io.Writer`.

Comment: Did you try `writer := &WriterMock{}`? My last example involved a type assertion to a pointer, and worked just fine.

Comment: @VonC , that didn't work. I tried `writer := &WriterMock{}` then `fileLogger := FileLogger{*writer}` and still test failed because the `[]byte` property is empty.

Comment: Why are you dereferencing `writer`? Pass it as a pointer and change the receiver of write to be a pointer too.

Comment: May I recommend working your way through the Go Tour at tour.golang.org and maybe studying Effective Go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep using a *pointer* to `WriterMock`, it should work:

```
func NewMockedFileLogger() *FileLogger{
    writer := &WriterMock{}
    fileLogger := FileLogger{writer}
    return &fileLogger
}
```

Then:

```
 assert.Equal(t, "Hello World!", string(fileLogger.File.(*WriterMock).data))
```

I missed:

```
func (this *WriterMock) Write(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
...
}
```

You need to call `Write()` on a pointer receiver, not a value receiver.
Since everything is passed by value in Go, using a value receiver would make a *copy* of the `WriterMock` instance.

Comment: I did that, and then when running the test, it panicked: `panic: interface conversion: io.Writer is logger.WriterMock, not *logger.WriterMock [recovered]
 panic: interface conversion: io.Writer is logger.WriterMock, not *logger.WriterMock`